# Cross domain issue preventing my ajax call to retrieve data from my express file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to retrieve and display data from my node/exprss file (app.js) and display it on my index.html. I make an ajax request to localhost:3000/turtles in my frontend.js file, but this is where I have cross domain issues.

APP.JS FILE

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/turtles', function(req, res){

    var turtles = {
      message: "success",
      data: [
        {
          name: "Raphael",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Leonardo",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Donatello",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Michelangelo",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        }
      ]
    };

    res.send(turtles.data[0].name);
});

app.listen(10000, function(){
    console.log("Port is on 10000!");
});
```

FRONTEND.JS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var names = [];
    var turtles = [];

    var myQueryUrl = "http://localhost:10000/turtles";

    $.ajax({url: myQueryUrl, method: 'GET'}).done(function(response){

            names = response.data;
            turtles.push(response.data);

            console.log(names)
            console.log(turtles)

            $('.DTurtles').append($('<p>' + name + '</p>'));


    }); 

});
```

I tried using sendFile('index.html') but I think that's not what I am looking for. Doing this will load my html on homepage (localhost:3000/), but I need to dynamically pull data from the turtles object (the names), and then display it on my html.

AlainIb, suggested I just return the entire turtle.data object and not just turtle.data.name. He also suggested I create a good path file like so

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', '../', 'client', 'index.html'));
});
```

I have all my files in the same directory. Can someone explain what the syntax above does. Why is it router.get and not app.get and particularly explain this part

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', '../', 'client', 'index.html'));
```

I also read that I should allow CORS by doing something like the following

```
app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
 });

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
 // Handle the post for this route
});
```

but I have no idea what all this does. Where does the next parameter in the app.all function come in from, and what is res.header? Will either of these solutions resolve my cross domain issues?

UPDATE: I added the following code in my get handler function that is suppose to return the data I am requesting with the ajax call:

```
app.get('/turtles', function(req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    var turtles = {
      message: "success",
      data: [
        {
          name: "Raphael",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Leonardo",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Donatello",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        },
        {
          name: "Michelangelo",
          favFood: "Pizza"
        }
      ]
    };

    res.send(turtles.data);
});
```

I no longer get the error message for cross domain issues; However, in my frontend.js, when I console.log turtles and names, it is showing it as undefined, which would mean I am not getting back the data. How can I get the data?

Comment: You're only sending the turtles.data which is an array `res.send(turtles.data)`, accessing `response.data` in the frontend will return `undefined`, since it does not have `data`. Do `res.send(turtles)` to send the whole data back, including message and data. then in your frontend, `response.data` should log the data

Comment: YESSS THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS. I would upvote your comment if I could but cant yet. Why do I have to send back the whole object? Is that how ajax calls to JSON objects work? The server side sends back the entire JSON object and then in front end code where ajax call is, we specifiy what data we want from the entire JSON object that was sent back such as the data array in turtles.data?

Comment: well technically it's up to you on how you want the data that is going to be consumed in the frontend looks like. In your case I'd think it makes sense to send the whole data as JSON format, as you can make use of the `"message"` to indicate whether the response is "success" or has "error". and the `"data"` would be the one that is processed, in your case probably to list the turtle's name and its favFood. And as @solarhell mentioned and the comments, you should use `res.json` instead.

Answer (score 1):

modify APP.JS from `res.send(...)` to  `res.json(...)`

Comment: what do you mean? Should I do res.json instead of res.send? Currently I have the turtle object as just a regular javascript object, but I know that if I put quotes around all the turtle properties/keys, it will be JSON object right? So does res.json just send the entire turtles object as a JSON object automatically?

Comment: `res.json()` will send the proper headers to let the ajax call know to parse the return data as json.